# Calling Oracle Stored Procedures from iReport 5.6 and JasperStudio 6.1

Tags: stored-procedures, jasper-reports

[image]I have an Oracle stored procedure within the package and I'm successfully run this stored procedure from Oracle SQL DEVELOPER and TOAD.

When I do call in iReport and Jasper Studio - no errors at all but report is blank, no records.

Is any idea?

Here is what I'm doing:

1. Query Language Executor is PLSQL;
   {call DA.PLZ0018_UNION_PR_PKG.UNION_PR_REPORT($P{ORACLE_REF_CURSOR}, $P{P_COMP_CODE}, $P{P_PAY_DATE})}
2. Stor proc in Oracle screen is attached:

[image: Stored Procedure to be called from iReport or Jasper Studio]

3. Screen shot is attached
   [image: Blank report in Jasper Studio 6.1]

Comment: is your procedure returning any records?

Comment: Hi Mani,                                                                                                         Yes, it's. Procedure is OK when running in TOAD or SQL DEVELOPER.

Comment: How do you achieve that $P{ORACLE_REF_CURSOR} is a valid parameter in Jaspersoft Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Simply reference the cursor fields by name.  For example, to get your first field, 'COMPANY_CODE', create a report field by the same name, then add it to your report.  I'm not sure if case matters.

As simple as this sounds, I had to work backwards from a simple test.  Try this if you are stuck:
Create a procedure in your existing package:
1) PROCEDURE get_test (p_refcur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_refcur FOR
        SELECT 'Testing' as test from dual;
END;

2) Create a field named 'test'.
3) Add field to detail pane.